# How do I conditionally assign a type depending upon one of the properties?

Tags: typescript

For example, I have:

```
interface Test {
  check:boolean;
  name:string;
}
```

If the `check` property is `true`, I want the `name` property to be optional instead of mandatory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#union-types) for this:

```
type Test = {
  check: true;
  name?: string;
} | {
  check: false;
  name: string;
}
```

The following examples would compile fine:

```
const ok1: Test = { check: true };
const ok2: Test = { check: true, name: 'foo' };
const ok3: Test = { check: false, name: 'bar' };
```

but this would raise an error:

```
const notOk: Test = { check: false };
```

specifically:

```
Type '{ check: false; }' is not assignable to type 'Test'.
  Property 'name' is missing in type '{ check: false; }' but required in type '{ check: false; name: string; }'.
```

Answer (score 1):

That is easily done using an union type, in your case it would look something like this:

```
type Test = {check:true, name?:string} | {check:false, name string}
```

Comment: That's not how you write optional properties.

Comment: Fixed! Thanks for pointing it out :) was stuck in a kotlin mindset